# Combining ErrorListPlot with another Plots

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to combine an ErrorListPlot with another Plots. Without the ErrorListPlot, it's working good. But, when I include it in the Show function, only the ErrorListPlot appears, and the other Plots are gone. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance,
Gabriel

Comment: Could you provide a simple code example of something that doesn't work? E.g., I've no problem with: `Show[ErrorListPlot[Table[{i, RandomReal[0.5]}, {i, 10}]],  Plot[{x^2, x}, {x, 0, 10}]]`

Comment: Here is an image with and without the ErrorListPlot inside the Show function: [link](http://imgur.com/a/rT5Bb). Thanks for your time, @JohnJosephM.Carrasco

Answer (score 1):

1. Without having access to your actual code & data, you're asking for people to help debug by glancing at your image.  You'll get better answers if you include a small working example that gets at your problem. (People like to tinker).  Worst case you can always paste your full example into [pastebin](https://pastebin.com) or [gist](https://gist.github.com).
2. `Show` has the plot range default to the first object, and you seem to have drastically different scales. In this case it looks like your y-intercept occurs higher than the scale of your error list plot.

I can reproduce with the following:

Here I'll plot the bigger one first so you can see all the data is actually there (if difficult to parse):

```
Show[Plot[{100 + x^13, 1000 + x^7}, {x, 0, 10}], 
 ErrorListPlot[Table[{i, RandomReal[0.5]}, {i, 10}]]]
```

yields:

[image]

Now let's see what happens when we do something similar to what you seem to have going on:

```
Show[ErrorListPlot[Table[{i, RandomReal[0.5]}, {i, 10}]], 
 Plot[{100 + x^13, 1000 + x^7}, {x, 0, 10}]]
```

yielding:

[image]

Note: Since we are stuck to the scale of the error list plot, and the other plot doesn't start until the y-axis is greater then 100 we don't see any of it.

We can start smashing them together by manually enlarging the plot range:

```
Show[ErrorListPlot[Table[{i, RandomReal[0.5]}, {i, 10}]], 
 Plot[{100 + x^13, 1000 + x^7}, {x, 0, 10}], PlotRange -> {0, 150}]
```

[image]

In this case things really don't belong on the same plot.  Maybe your data won't look so crazy when you include your `PlotRange->{0,3}`

Comment: You are right! Inside my messy code, I've changed some data that completely altered the scale of the lines. I found it and then the Show function worked pretty fine. Thank you!